# Store global variables in ArcPad that store user information

Tags: arcpad

I know that it's possible to store global variables in ArcPad from reading the help files.  I have several field staff that are out everyday -- generally we have them select their name from a "Specialist" domain for each data point they create.

Is it possible to store a table somewhere in the background of ArcPad that stores the user's information that can be used to auto-populate fields such as Specialist (user-name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use an applet. Much like the AddXYZ applet does, the applet looks for a field in your table, if the field exists, it reads values from your GPS receiver and stores them in the corresponding field. You could add an entry to this applet like USERNAME and set it's value to the owner of the device.

If multiple people were using the same device this might not be the best method.

You could also do it this way which is probably easier to implement in an Enterprise Environment.

http://arcpadteam.blogspot.com/2009/07/arcpad-login-form.html

If you want the user name to stick each time just comment out or delete this from the code

Set pForm = Nothing

because you would want it to remember the username specified the first time so the user does not have to pick their name each time.

Comment: Have you had any luck implementing the log-in form?  I've gotten to the point where I can 'Alert' the user name back in a message box, but all my attempts to write the name in a control box have failed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Any luck?